# Need a Magento Event that will fire after changing the shipping address of an order

Tags: magento, magento2

I have been trying events left and right trying to find one that fires right after updating the shipping address of an order via the magento admin.

I have tried a number of things I found on here, as well as sales_order_place_after (which is a hook I use for the frontend events), but for the adminhtml events, I cant seem to get my method to fire when I save the changes.

Can anyone point me in the direction of the event I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by doing a little hacking:

The event that you need to bind in this case is adminhtml_sales_order_addressSave.

I found this by creating a global event observer, which simply monitored all the events occurring on the server:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <add_event>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MGD_Shippingodbc_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>trackEvents</method>
                </add_event>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
     </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Then I added this function to my class:

```
 function trackEvents($observer)
 {
    Mage::log("track event:" . $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName());

    return $this;
 }
```

Interestingly enough, I also realized I can use this same methodology to create my own event dispatchers as well, simply by monitoring the events as they come through this observer function, like this:

```
function trackEvents($observer)
{
   if ($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == "adminhtml_sales_order_addressSave")
       Mage::dispatchEvent('my_custom_event_observer', []);

       return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
    controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShiping
```

Comment: That didnt seem to work either... I tried your suggestion as it was, and with saveShipping (sp corrected). 

I also tried snooping around in the form found at the magento admin -> orders -> view order -> edit shipping address... 

controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_addressSave

This also didnt fire the event I need it to.

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.